# Calendar Element not getting selected- Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am learning automation with selenium Webdriver(Java) and I wanted to practice some stuff on [this webpage.](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/us/homepage)

I am having trouble selecting a particular date using date picker. Here is my code which attempts to do that:

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
String subWindow = null;
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ns_7_CO19VHUC6VU280AQ4LUKRK0IR7_fmOutboundDateDisplay']")).click(); //Clicking on datepicker icon

// Change to a new window
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
String subWindow = null;
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator1 = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindow = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindow);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='calendarBodyContainer']/tr[2]/td[3]/span")).click(); //Departure Date- 10Feb/2015
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='calendarBodyContainer']/tr[4]/td[4]/span")).click(); //Arrival Dtae- 25 Feb/2015
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='calendarBodyContainer']/tr[2]/td[3]/span"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 3.12 seconds

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you mistook the **calendar widget as new window and automated accordingly**, which resulted in the element not found, rightly suspected by **@alecxe**

Please try the below code and see if it works out for you.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Navigating to the site
driver.get("http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/us/homepage");

//Clicking on the Departing field to select date
driver.findElement(By.id("ns_7_CO19VHUC6VU280AQ4LUKRK0IR7_fmOutboundDateDisplay")).click();

//Selecting Feb 10, 2015 for departure date 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@dojoattachpoint = 'calRightNode']//span[.='10']")).click();

//Waiting for the return calendar with "Return" as the header to appear
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@dojoattachpoint='calHeadlineNode' and contains(text(),'Return')]")));

//Selecting Feb 26, 2015 for returning date
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@dojoattachpoint = 'calLeftNode']//span[.='26']")).click();
```

**NOTE:** I have added [explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) for waiting for the Return text in the "Return Calendar widget" because it overlaps the Departing/Outbound Calendar, and hence selenium needs a little time to detect the change in DOM.

Comment: Perfect solution man. Thanks a bunch. I had already realized that the problem lied in switching the window but; I also had hard time figuring the right X-path. I came up with something like this:       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='lh_calendarMatrix']/div[.='February 2015']/following-sibling::table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/span[. ='12']")).click(); //Arrival Date -12 Feb/2015

Answer (score 1):

I would try two things:

- try the following `xpath` (relying on the `table` element and `span`'s text):

  ```
  //table[@class='calendarContainer'][1]//span[. = '09']
  ```
- [explicitly waiting for an element](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits):

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[@class='calendarContainer'][1]//span[. = '09']"))).click();
  ```

I'm also not sure about the *necessity of switching windows* here.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, its not working. There are multiple dates, matching that xpath

Comment: @Nik_stack multiple? You mean two, right - in the left and right calendars? Anyway, updated - using the `[1]` to search inside the first one. Please check.

Comment: :I tried using [1]. However, if I try to evaluate the command on firepath, it still highlights both dates (from right and left calendars). When I execute the command using webdriver anyway, it does not find that element.